Query parameter causing error on semrush SEO
My requirement was to pre-fill one specific field of webform using query parameter and I have done it but due query parameter semrush (SEO) is claiming hundreds of pages as duplicate for example some page links:
https://mywebsite.com/en/project-form?products_info=abc
https://mywebsite.com/en/project-form?products_info=cd
https://mywebsite.u-blox.com/en/project-form?products_info=abc

There are hundreds of pages like above which semrush says has duplicate title tags and meta descriptions because it is considering it as separate page but actually it is only one webform and it's causing an error after adding query parameter.
let languageConvContact = linkFix(
    `/${language}/project-form?products_info=${variantTitle}` // here I added query parameter
  );

I have tried to add query parameter into robots.txt file like:
Disallow: ?*products_info

but it actually does not help.

You're right, search engines like Semrush can treat URLs with query parameters as duplicate content, causing SEO issues. Here are two approaches to address this:

Prevent Indexing of URLs with Query Parameters: This approach tells search engines to ignore URLs with specific query parameters. However, it's important to understand the implications:

Add the following line to your robots.txt file:
Disallow: /*?products_info=*
Thus search engines won't crawl and index these URLs. Users who directly access these links won't see them in search results.

Use Canonicalization:
This approach tells search engines that these URLs with query parameters are variations of the main "/en/project-form" page. It helps consolidate SEO value:
In your form's HTML code, add a  tag with the rel="canonical" attribute:

<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/en/project-form">


do I need to use above two approaches you share or should I only use Disallow: /?products_info= into robots.txt will that work?

You need to just apply one of them. If you did that already, then it should work
